# Image Batch Processing: Remove horizontal slice of an image and fill its void by the surrounding areas from above and/or below

Tags: gimp, photoshop-scripting, batch-processing, crop, copy-and-paste

### Original Images & Desired Outcome

I have a batch of PNG images which need the same automated image processing:

- Middle part (red) shall get eliminated entirely and its void filled from above/below
- Top (blue) and middle part (red) always have the same height
- The bottom part (green) may vary in height

[image: Original and Desired Outcome]

## How do I achieve this in an image editor with macro/scripting capabilities?

### I came up with the following possible procedures

- Sorted from most desired with fewest processing steps,
- To least desired with most processing steps, but if not possible
  otherwise, fine with it too.

##### Approach 1: Eliminate undesired portion and void gets filled by neighboring areas

[image: Eliminate undesired portion and void gets filled by neighboring areas]

##### Approach 2: Move desired part so that it covers undesired part entirely and then crop to be without void

[image: Move desired part so that it covers undesired part entirely and then crop to be without void]

##### Approach 3: Move desired part over undesired but larger part - Then crop remainder and void

[image: Move desired part over undesired but larger part. Then crop remainder and void.]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  I don't think this would work in Photoshop with an Action and Batch operation.  The problem is that the green part would vary, and the height of the result would be different each time.  Actions can only repeat the exact same steps over and over. Photoshop has no decision making capabilities based on content. It doesn't know anything about an image, it's just a dumb machine. What you want to do would likely require specialist programming/scripting with some kind of image analysis, and that would be off-topic for this site unfortunately.

Comment: 1) Thanks for confirming that in Photoshop only fixed dimensions would work. Well in the case of my batch, I have i.e. 50% with this green height and i.e. 30% with another height, and only 20% with very varying heights. So to cover the 50% + 30% I could just record two different macros, and only do the 20% per hand.

Comment: 2) Hence the request for an ImageMagick command line.

Comment: And no image analysis necessary: Width is always full width (100%). Height of desired blue horizontal slice is a fixed value (i.e. 50px), height of the undesired red slice is also fixed (i.e. 90px) and height of the green is the remainder of the height (100%-50px-90px).

I'm 100% sure this is possible in ImageMagick. Someone versed in it surely can formulate the command line in 2min. I already studied the manual for 2 hours and have not yet grasped it. Help would be appreciated!

Asked at Super User. They told me Graphics Design would be better. Maybe also wrong. Maybe StackOverflow?

Comment: Yes if you can narrow it down to two or three different Photoshop Actions for each of those sizes, then that would work.  It is possible to write scripts for GIMP, but it has no actions recording like Photoshop. Krita has macro recording capabilities though. Imagemagick may also work, although I don't have enough experience with it to help here. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: @BillyKerr, just for the record: It *is* possible to record such an action in Photoshop which will work with a green area in any height. For example using *Canvas Size* like [this](https://i.imgur.com/5ybc59d.gif).

Comment: Yucks: Just learned [ImageMagick cannot combine percent and pixels in it's geometry argument](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=17441). But ok, I do not need percentage per se. If it has special variables height and width and I can integrate that into my geometry expression this is sufficient, like `totalHeight-50px-90px`.

Comment: @Wolff cool, your recording shows the solution in Photoshop already. Do you know of an equivalent macro for a free GUI image editing/processing app?

Comment: @Wolff could you please share the PS macro file depicted in your screen recording? Maybe as my fallback solution I could consider installing the 7 day free trial of Adobe Creative Cloud. And then having the macro ready would sure help having this done asap. A solution with a free or somehow more affordable (<40 EUR) GUI or CLI app would still be preferred.

Comment: @Wolff your screen recording only shows original and result and the steps nearby. Could you be so kind to re-record it in a way wich runs through all the intermediary steps of the macro? That way I could even better understand what goes on.

Comment: It runs all the steps but it's just too fast to record. Actually you can see all steps in the Actions panel on the left. But I can add an answer explaining the steps.

Comment: @Wolff - cool, I'd never have though of that. Nice trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a recipe for an action for **Photoshop**. I know you specifically states that you don't have access to Photoshop, but it might be useful to know the method anyway.

We assume that:

- All your images are flattened (only consists of a *Background Layer*).
- The images have different width and height.
- The top part which you want to keep (in blue) is always *50 px* tall.
- The middle part which you want to cut out (in red) is always *90 px* tall.

### Method

We start out with an image like this:

[image]

Open the *Actions* panel, create a new *Set*, create a new *Action* within that set and start recording.

Perform *Image > Canvas Size* and set it up like this:

[image]

Make sure *Relative* is unticked. Set the *Height* field to *50 px* and don't touch the *Width* field. Set the *Anchor* to *center top*.

This will crop away everything except for the top part, which you want to keep:

[image]

Perform *Select > All* and *Edit > Copy* to copy the top part of the image to the clipboard for later use.

Perform *File > Revert* to revert the image to its initial state:

[image]

Again perform *Image > Canvas Size* but this time with these settings:

[image]

Make sure *Relative* is ticked. Set the *Height* field to *-90 px* and leave the *Width* field at *0*. Set the *Anchor* to *center bottom*.

This will crop away the top 90 px of the image:

[image]

Perform *Edit > Paste* to paste in the top part of the image we copied to the clipboard earlier:

[image]

The pasted content gets its own layer which is selected by default. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and left-click the *Background* layer to select that as well.

In the *Options* panel in the top, click the *Align top edges* button to align the top part with the top of the background:

[image]

Finally, perform *Layer > Flatten Image* to flatten the image and get the final result:

[image]

Running the action looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Still very much appreciated though being a solution for Photoshop for these reasons: 1) I may get a PS trial just to perform this batch which I need to do (and if satisfied I may subscribe for a bit) 2) Great recipe, as it gives ideas how it could be done with image editors having similar macro/scripting capabilites.

Gave it an upvote at least. Would accept an answer which shows how to do this with GIMP or ImageMagick. Thank you very much Wolff!

Comment: @porg - well you could do the same thing in GIMP manually, but GIMP has no macro/action recording. You can use scripts written in ScriptFu or Python in GIMP, but coding is generally off-topic here, as already explained.  Perhaps you could ask on Stack Overflow. Good luck anyway.

Comment: @BillyKerr I narrowed the solution scope to GUI image editors with macro/scripting capabilities and hence accepted your greatly written and illustrated Photoshop answer! Thanks again!    Will try the programmatic/scripting approach now with ImageMagick myself. And at a more suited forum share if I find a solution in a separate Q&A or ask the question again there.

Comment: Studying the ImageMagick manpages further was eventually worth it. ImageMagick [-chop](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#chop) does all what I wanted in a single operation  Also interesting is its functional counterpart [-splice](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#splice). Wrote a [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71470153/199400) with command line explanation and illustrations.

Comment: @porg, nice! I've dabbled with ImageMagick, but since I never *really* need it for anything it's just for fun. It's good to know it exists though. Might come in handy one day.

Comment: For impatient future readers: There's also a StackExchange solution for this as a [ImageMagick -chop command line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71470153/199400)